# Printing DataTables on same Page one after another

Tags: c#, winforms

I am searching for best way to do the task below, suggestion(s) also welcome. I am using Window form in C#

There are two DataTables in dataSet, first one consists of:

```
pk_Col1 int, Col2_Name varchar, Col3_Detail1 varchar, Col4_Detail2 varchar, Col5_Detail3 varchar
```

and the other one has:

```
Pk2_Col1 int, Name varchar, Detail2 varchar, Detail3 varchar
```

Now i want  to fetch rows from each table to print and preview on PageDocument and order of rows of tables is one after another.

to best describe see image...

Comment: Did you forgot to include the image?

Comment: Sorry For image, but u did enough what i mean....<br/>

Comment: So, what is your approach to the problem so far?

Comment: I think... bind datatables with two different DataGridView and print both on same page... but i want to print rows of tables directly from datatable... without datagridview control...,,, my question is.. how make it possible